# React passing props to other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

Hello I am having trouble passing props between components. I can't share the exact code so I made a simplified version. I am not getting any console errors, though login is obviously 'undefined' Any insight is appreciated!

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function App() {
  
 
  const [login, setLogin] = useState('Jpm91297');

  const changeState = () => {
    const newLogin = document.getElementById('loginData').value;
    setLogin(newLogin);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Fancy API Call!!!</h1>
      <form onSubmit={() => changeState()}>
          <input type='text' id='loginData'></input>
          <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Api.Js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Api = ( { login } ) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then(setData);
      }, []);
    
      if (data) {
        return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
      }
    
      return <div>No data Avail</div>

}

export default Api;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Api from './api'

ReactDOM.render(
    <>
    <App />
    <Api />
    </>,
    
   
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: (1) You are not preventing the default form action from occurring. This reloads the app. (2) You should lift the `login` state to the common parent of `App` and `Api` so it can be passed down as a prop.

Comment: In addition to what @DrewReese correctly notes, I see that your input in `App` is what is called an "uncontrolled" component, and this is generally a bad idea. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components. (And note that if you must use an uncontrolled component, using a ref is a much better way to do it than direct DOM queries like `document.getElementById`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not preventing the default form action from occurring. This reloads the app.
2. You should lift the `login` state to the common parent of `App` and `Api` so it can be passed down as a prop. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Example:

index.js

Move the `login` state to a parent component so that it can be passed down as props to the children components that care about it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Api from './api';

const Root = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState('Jpm91297');

  return (
    <>
      <App setLogin={setLogin} />
      <Api login={login} />
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App

Pass the `changeState` callback directly as the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler and prevent the default action. Access the form field from the `onSubmit` event object.

```
function App({ setLogin }) {
  const changeState = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newLogin = event.target.loginData.value;
    setLogin(newLogin);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Fancy API Call!!!</h1>
      <form onSubmit={changeState}>
        <input type='text' id='loginData'></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Api

```
const Api = ({ login }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setData);
  }, [login]); // <-- add login dependency so fetch is made when login changes
    
  if (data) {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
  }
    
  return <div>No data Avail</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit react-passing-props-to-other-components]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! quick question: how did you get your version to work without removing the empty array passed as a second argument to the useEffect()? Mine would not work until I removed it

Comment: @JordanMcKinney Do you mean for the `fetch` request?

Comment: Yes Sir, it wouldn't refresh the data upon clicking the button without removing it

Comment: @JordanMcKinney Oops, typo on my part, apologies. I had added the `login` prop as a dependency so when the form was submitted and the `login` state/prop changed, data would be refetched. You don't generally want to completely remove the dependency array, but only specify the external values that are referenced internally.